# htaccess SEO friendly url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My url to specific site looks like this:

http://www.mytestingsite123.com/play.php?alias=this-is-an-alias#.U5BPYvl_tNo

but I want to have this url:

http://www.mytestingsite123.com/this-is-an-alias

or

http://www.mytestingsite123.com/video/this-is-an-alias

so it will be more SEO friendly. Could you please help me, how could I do that by modifying .htaccess file.

I have .htaccess file with following content:

```
RewriteEngine On

# whole domains
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]

# subdomains
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

# aliases (if misssing)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

# subdomains (if misssing)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append your `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]+)?$ play.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ play.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

The first rule will match 
http://www.mytestingsite123.com/video/this-is-an-alias

the second rule would match 
http://www.mytestingsite123.com/this-is-an-alias

the `[L]` tells apache to stop looking for a rule, you could change it to `[L,QSA]` which means if you add extra params at the end of the new uri it would pass them on properly.

Comment: I tried it, but nothing changed. Even though if I only tried to simple remove .php extension nothing have changed.